# Sending value of a select tag to a PHP page as a POST variable

Tags: php, html

I have a select tag with different values as shown below.
I want to send the selected value to a PHP page as a POST variable or any other way.
Is this possible?

```
<select id="city" name="city" align="left">
<option value="Pune">Pune</option>
<option value="Bhopal">Bhopal</option>
<option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
<option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please don't take this as rude. I mean it as constructive. Your question shows a complete lack of understanding of how PHP interacts with web pages. Do some reading. Search Google for "php form handling".

Comment: It's not possible till you will know how works php, html(or javascript). To send via html in post use `<form>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: @TecBrat and Epsil0neR : thanks for the comments.Here I want to send the value of select tag without using form .I mean I dont want to use submit button to send this.Whenever user changes the value of drop down,I want to send the selected value to a new PHP page a POST variable.hope this clarifies

Answer (score 1):

Put your select inside a form. Give the form an `action` that is a php file. give it the `method` of `post` and include a `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` inside the form as well.

Then, in your php file you will access the `$_POST` array

```
echo $_POST['city'];
```

If you'd like to submit it without the button, you'll need to use javascipt's [onChange](http://help.dottoro.com/ljoiurdq.php) event.

Comment: I dont want to use Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's very simple. You have to use the from tag : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp and learn a little of PHP and HTML basic interaction

```
<form action = 'myPage.php' method = 'post'>
<select id="city" name="city" align="left">
<option value="Pune">Pune</option>
<option value="Bhopal">Bhopal</option>
<option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
<option value="New Delhi">New Delhi</option>
</select>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'send' value = 'send'/>
</form>
```

(I also added a button son send data)

in myPage.php :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['city'])){
     echo isset($_POST['city'];
}
?>
```